# solve equation with logarithm base 2

Tags: logarithms, radicals

Solve in IR: I tried but traditionally couldn t be solved.

$\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-1}} + \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-1}} +log_2(x-1)=0$

Comment: It's not a linear equation. I'm guessing it can't be solved in closed terms, but only solved numerically.

Comment: By the way, write $\$$\log$\$$ to generate $\log$ as opposed to $log$.

Comment: Why? It denotes a base other than 10, only Log to denote base 10.

Answer (score 1):

As Gerry Myerson commented, there is no closed form expression of the zero of function $$f(x)=\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-1}} + \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-1}} +\log_2(x-1)$$ By inspection, we know that the solution is between $x=1$ and  $x=2$ since $f(2)=1+\sqrt{3}$.

We can have a quite good approximation of the solution using the Taylor expansion at $x=1$
$$\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-1}} + \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-1}}=2+\frac{3 (x-1)}{4}+O\left((x-1)^{2}\right)$$ which makes, at least locally,

$$f(x) \approx \frac{3 (x-1)}{4}+\frac{\log (x-1)}{\log (2)}+2$$ the solution of which being given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).
$$x=1+\frac{4 }{3 \log (2)}W\left(\frac{3 \log (2)}{16}\right)$$ Since the argument is quite small, you can evaluate
$$W(z)=z-z^2+\frac{3 z^3}{2}-\frac{8 z^4}{3}+\frac{125 z^5}{24}+O\left(z^6\right)$$ which is given in the linked page. Using it, the *approximate* solution is then $\approx 1.22267$ while the "exact" solution would be $\approx 1.22250$.

If you need more accuracy, just use Newton method with, for example, $x_0=1.5$  and get the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.5000000000000000000 \\
 1 & 1.1203284150829764246 \\
 2 & 1.1959735634030846971 \\
 3 & 1.2210074897823484868 \\
 4 & 1.2224983881275373905 \\
 5 & 1.2225029048928075835 \\
 6 & 1.2225029049338946555
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for twenty significant figures.

**Edit**

An interesting (at least to me) generalization would be to find the zero of 
$$g(x)=\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-1}} + \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-1}} +\log_a(x-1)$$ Using the same procedure, the approximate solution would be given by
$$x=1+\frac{4 }{3 \log (a)}W\left(\frac{3 \log (a)}{4a^2}\right)\tag 1$$ which can be approximated by the simple 
$$x=1+\frac 1{a^2}-\frac{3 \log (a)}{4 a^4}+\frac{27 \log ^2(a)}{32 a^6}+\cdots\tag 2$$

Looking at a few values of $a$, here are the approximate and exact results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & \text{from } (1) & \text{from } (2)& \text{exact} \\
 2 & 1.22267 & 1.22384 &  1.22250 \\
 3 & 1.10214 & 1.10234 &  1.10210 \\
 4 & 1.05879 & 1.05883 &  1.05878 \\
 5 & 1.03820 & 1.03821 &  1.03819\\
 6 & 1.02680 & 1.02680 &  1.02679 \\
 7 & 1.01983 & 1.01983 &  1.01983 \\
 8 & 1.01526 & 1.01526 &  1.01526 \\
 9 & 1.01210 & 1.01210 &  1.01210 \\
 10 & 1.00983 & 1.00983 & 1.00983
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Neatly done! Thanks

Comment: I had someone done a great job solving the equation by removing the square roots and leaving an absolute value of both and creating two intervals, by which you only get an answer in one interval, x= 5/4, why there would be a need to take those square roots?

Comment: @J.Moh. Could you give more details ? As far as I can see, there is only one real root to the equation.

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2915745/closed-form-solution-for-logarithmic-inequality